# Not able to scaffold a controller in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to scaffold controller for Entity Framework Core using ASP.NET Core Web API 3.1.

My database works fine, I can add new migrations and update the actual database.

The problem is that, once I install the packages and try to scaffold a new controller, the package version from `5.0.3` goes down to `3.1.12` for `EntityFramework.Tools` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer`.

What happens is that, I install the required versions of `EntityFrameworkCore`, `EntityFrameworkCore.Design`, `EntityFramework.Tools` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer`, in my case I install them as `5.0.3` version. Once installed, I'm trying to scaffold a new controller with entity framework like this:

1. Click right mouse on the Controllers folder and click `Add`
2. Select `New Scaffold Item`
3. Select `API Controller with actions, using EntityFramework`

Unfortunately, I'm not able to create a controlled. I'm getting the error below:

> There was an error running the selected Code Generator: 'Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ConsoleLogger' from assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools.Program.Main(String [] args)

What I've tried:

1. Clearing Nuget cache
2. Uninstalling and installing all the packages all over again
3. Updating visual studio version
4. Adding additional attributes to my csproj file for the actual packages.
5. Creating a new empty project, installing the packages and scaffolding a controller. It still does not work??
6. Reinstalling visual studio

This stack question did not help me:

[ASP.NET Core 1.1.1 MVC with EF Core - not able to scaffold from controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975449/asp-net-core-1-1-1-mvc-with-ef-core-not-able-to-scaffold-from-controller-class)

I don't understand. I update my packages versions to `5.0.3` but once I try to scaffold a new controller, the package versions are being downgrade to `3.1.12` automatically.

How is this possible? Any additional ideas, how I could fix this issue?

Comment: I've found a solution. I've updated ASP.NET core version to 5.0 and updated all my nuget packages once again.

Comment: I tried to add controller scaffolding tried to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` which was already installed so I went back to NuGet packages manager`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` version was different than rest of the packages so I upgraded following to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` version number.

    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Rest of the packages were automatically  installed during scaffolding process.